# Using Bootstrap With The Template Tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web-component, html5-template, html-imports

I've been learning the vanilla version of web components and have run into a snag. When trying to use the grid from bootstrap inside of a template tag, specifically the container class, it does not apply any bootstrap styling to it.

```
//Template File
<template>

  <top-bar>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  </top-bar>

</template>

<script>
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('top-bar');
  if(el != null) {
    //Custom Elements
    document.registerElement('top-bar');
    //Import Elements
    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      var shadow = el[i].createShadowRoot();
      var template = document.querySelector('#topbar').import.querySelector('template');
      var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
      shadow.appendChild(clone);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The general Bootstrap stylings (fonts, style resets etc.) are being applied correctly and no console errors are coming up.

```
//Index File
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Components</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="import" href="topbar.html" id="topbar">
</head>
<body>

  <top-bar></top-bar>

</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

I've attempted to put the link and script files for bootstrap in the template file (but outside of the template tags as link tags will not get rendered in a template tag). Bootstrap will load as if I were calling it on the index page, but the container still will not inherit any styles from Bootstrap.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow DOM stops the CSS propagation.
Don't use Shadow DOM if you want natural CSS propagation.

```
var shadow = el[i] //.createShadowRoot();  //will work
```

PS:

1°) Your use of `<template>` is wrong: don't get nested `<top-bar>` tags.

2°) Your use of registerElement is pointless. Give a prototype to your new element.

A correct implementation of topbar.html for Custom Element and Template, with no Shadow DOM would be:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

//Import Elements
var template = document.querySelector('#topbar').import.querySelector('template');

//Custom Elements
var topBar = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )

topBar.createdCallback = function ()
{
    var shadow = this //.createShadowRoot()
    var clone = document.importNode( template.content, true );
    shadow.appendChild( clone );
}

document.registerElement( 'top-bar', { prototype: topBar } );

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please be aware of this message I'm getting as of March-1st-2019 google Chrome:

[Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more details.

So now, insteadOf :
document.registerElement( 'approve-btn', { prototype: myCustomElement } );

... now seems we need to do:

```
customElements.define("approve-btn", myCustomElement);
```

where mycustomElement should be a classs like this:

```
class ApproveBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call parent constructor first
    super();

    // Get template content from DOM
    this.template = document.getElementById("approve-btn");
    this.templateContent = this.template.content;

    this.appendChild(this.templateContent);


  }
 }
```

and then finally execute:

```
customElements.define("approve-btn", ApproveBtn);
```